# how to wrap an image onto an irregular shaped object

Tags: edit-mode

I have found some video tutorials none of which shows me how to wrap an image onto the side of an irregular shaped object.
I have an image of a sign I want to place on the side of a simple building which has a sloping flat roof. No matter what I try I cannot stop the image looking bent even though it is placed on a flat face on my object. What do I need to do. Here is the image of the sign and the object in Blender showing that it is bent.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to edit mode.
2. Select face with logo.
3. Go to side view (<kbd>Num 1</kbd>, if I'm not mistaken)
4. Press <kbd>U</kbd> -> Project from view.
5. If it doesn't help, change texture mapping to UV

Comment: Thanks. Perfect. At first when I pressed Num 1 (side view) to displayed the opposite side but thankfully I just dragged the object to view the other side. Something else learned.